# MacOs - localhost file not found 404

Tags: php, macos, symfony, localhost, http-status-code-404

Can someone please help.

I was running successfully my *Symfony* project via *Docker* containers. Suddenly when I access `http://localhost/` I get the `File not found.` **error**?
I now that it means that system can not locate my files, but I am not sure what happened.

I see that my containers are built and running okay.
Also the same message I get when I try to test app endpoints through Postman.

I am on Mac `Monterey 12.4`.

Everything was working fine couple of hours ago. I just switched branches to change something, then switched back. The problem was on both branches..

Can someone help, I do not know what to do?

Docker config:

```
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-12}-alpine
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-name}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-pass}
            POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
        volumes:
            - $PWD/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        profiles:
            - db-in-docker
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - symfony
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine"
        command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
          - $PWD/redis-data:/var/lib/redis
          - $PWD/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        environment:
          - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
        networks:
          - symfony
    php:
        container_name: "backend_php"
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
            target: dev
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - symfony_docker_app_sync:/var/www/symfony/
        depends_on:
            - redis
        networks:
            - symfony
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www/symfony/
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - symfony
        env_file:
            - .env.nginx.local
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why do you don´t use the built in symfony server for local development? However - how looks your docker container configuration for your webserver?

Comment: I was following the docker config from the project documentation. I updated my question. Maybe it is docker related as docker was maybe crashing few times.. I have the newest version and all containers are running.. @DerSausH

Comment: It looks right to me but please change the port to something  else - maybe 8000:8000 because mac os have a built in webserver - i can not exclude that the built in server is also running, therefore the port forwarding will not work.

Comment: This does not work, also. :/ @DerSausH